# Count the number of occurrence of a number in string of numbers using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a requirement where I want to count the number of times a particular number appeared in the string of numbers using Google Bigquery.

e.g
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select raw_data, 
  ( select count(*)
    from unnest(split(raw_data)) el
    where el = '1'
  ) as appearances
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Another option would be

```
select raw_data, 
  array_length(regexp_extract_all(raw_data, r'\b1\b')) as appearances
from your_table
```

with same output, obviously

Comment: Thank you so much. The second option suits best for my requirement. Thank you